# Derivative of two variables function $ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-\tan(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}=0 $

Tags: limits, derivatives

For given the function $f\in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which has this property that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-\tan(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}=0
$$
How can I find $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)$?

**My approach:**

As we know that $f\in C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ so we can see that  $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(0,0)$. But don't know  what do next?

Comment: First of all we get $f(0,0)=0$ since otherwise it will contradict to the assumption.  Next I recommend you to expand $f(x,y)$ and $\tan(x)\sin(y)$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: So @Fergns do you mean that $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} \left(y \left(x f^{(1,1)}(0,0)+y f^{(0,2)}(0,0)\right)+x
   \left(x f^{(2,0)}(0,0)+y f^{(1,1)}(0,0)\right)\right)+x f^{(1,0)}(0,0)+y
   f^{(0,1)}(0,0)+f(0,0)$ and $\tan(x)\sin(y)=xy$?